# Add X number of columns to a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to add a varying number (X) of columns with 0 to an existing data.frame within a function.

Here is an example data.frame:

```
dt <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=4:6)
```

I would like to get this result if X=1 :

```
  a x y
1 0 1 4
2 0 2 5
3 0 3 6
```

And this if X=3 :

```
  a b c x y
1 0 0 0 1 4
2 0 0 0 2 5
3 0 0 0 3 6
```

What would be an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A second option is `cbind`

```
f <- function(x, n = 3) {
  cbind.data.frame(matrix(
    0,
    ncol = n,
    nrow = nrow(x),
    dimnames = list(NULL, letters[1:n])
  ), x)
}

f(dt, 5)
#  a b c d e x y
#1 0 0 0 0 0 1 4
#2 0 0 0 0 0 2 5
#3 0 0 0 0 0 3 6
```

NOTE: because `letters` has a length of 26 the function would need some adjustment regarding the naming scheme if `n > 26`.

Answer (score 3):

We can assign multiple columns to '0' based on the value of 'X'

```
X <- 3
nm1 <- names(dt)
dt[letters[seq_len(X)]] <- 0
dt[c(setdiff(names(dt), nm1), nm1)]
```

---

Also, we can use `add_column` from `tibble` and create columns at a specific location

```
library(tibble)
add_column(dt, .before = 1,  !!!setNames(as.list(rep(0, X)), 
        letters[seq_len(X)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

- You can try the code below

```
dt <- cbind(`colnames<-`(t(rep(0,X)),letters[seq(X)]),dt)
```

- If you don't care the column names of added columns, you can use just

```
dt <- cbind(t(rep(0,X)),dt)
```

which is much shorter